# Is it possible to read data from a Microsoft Access database into a button in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba

I've programmed for a few semesters in C++ and I'm just starting Visual Basic. Although it was a pre-req for a class I'm taking now, my professor thought I could learn on my own for the course. However I'm having a hard time with our first project, which is meant to be pretty simple.
We simply have to create a GUI representation of the periodic table, and create it in a way where the user will click on an element and be presented with its information as well as a picture.

We are given a database file which contains each element's name, abbreviation, atomic number, and atomic weight.

My plan was to create the table using a button for each element which, when clicked, would open a new form with the elements picture and all the information.

However, I can't figure out how to transfer the element's abbreviation, its atomic number, and its weight from the database to the button.

I guess what I want to do is somehow create a loop that goes through all the entries in the database and then write the information to the button, instead of just having to enter all that information manually.

I hope this makes sense. I'm really struggling with it.

Comment: Do you want to display the element info in the button (like in a periodic table)?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would like to display the atomic number, abbreviation, and weight!
I cannot, however, for the life of me figure out how to do this!

Comment: I figured out how to add the database to the project, just can't figure out how to iteratively create the buttons. I don't even know if this is possible, or if I just have to create each one manually.

Comment: So you will be clicking the button based on that caption and add the data into the database? interesting..

Comment: Do you mean VB (VB.Net) or VBA (which is a different language altogether, despite some strong similarities) ?

Comment: If you are using Access VBA you can use the CreateControl Method
[as in here](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1655935-vba-createcontrol-button.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my knowledge, you can only add buttons on an Access form on Design view. You cannot dynamically add controls on normal view, ie, in a clickable mode. I propose an idea for the first step:

I. You should add all your elements on the form manually like this on the design view:
[image]

All buttons must be named like cmdH for H, cmdHe for He, ... cmdFe for Fe, ...

II. For each button you assign the onclick event through it's properties sheet as:

```
OnClick="=prvDoClick()"
```

III. On the private module of the form on VBA, activable through Alt-F11, type this code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
'
Private Function prvDoClick()
'
  Dim strSymbol As String
'
  strSymbol = Mid(Me.ActiveControl.Name, 4)
'
' show symbol for debug, comment it after debugging:
'
  MsgBox strSymbol
'
' here do what you want about the element with the symbol strSymbol, like H, He:
'
'
  prvDoClick = True
'
End Function
'
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'
' customize:
'
'
End Sub
```

IV. Double-click on the form on your Navigation Pane, it shows like this:
[image]

If you Click on the button B for example, a message "B" will be shown on the popup Message box.

V. If you like, you can download the Access 2007 file (372kb) free of virus checked by Norton 2013 at [frm.accdb](http://www.asia-home.com/errors/frm.accdb).

This is just a beginning step. Good programming.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you are doing this is vb.net or in microsoft access natively in vba, but the idea is basically the same.  if working in accesss, you can already access all your data in tables and queries.  if in vb.net, you'll need to create a connection to the access file with code similar to this:

```
    oleConn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

    oleConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                               "Data Source=C:\Test.mdb;"
    oleConn.Open()
```

the key is the OleDbConnection object.  pay attention to the ConnectionString and make sure you supply the correct provider and the proper filename.  once you have the connection open, you can query the database with access (jet) SQL and get the data out into a DataTable. you can find tons of information on using OleDb, but that should get you started.

so now you have the data you need.  set up the form with a button for each element.  name each button by the atomic number it represents.  then you can pull the data from the table into a Recordset/DataTable, move through each row, and populate the corresponding button's Caption/Text.  for example, in vba, using access' native data objects, this is a rough sketch of how it could be done:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDB()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY AtomicNumber")

rst.MoveFirst

Do Until rst.EOF
    Form("MyForm").Controls(rst.Fields("AtomicNumber")).Caption = rst.Fields("Abbreviation")

    .MoveNext
Loop
```

the key idea here is that the buttons themselves have a unique identifying element which can be linked back to the unique identifying element in the data (in this case AtomicNumber).

as far as getting the other information when a button is clicked, you can leverage the db access code again and run SQL against the database where the AtomicNumber is equal to the button name.  you will have a Recordset/DataTable with all the fields you specified in the SQL query and do with it what you wish.

hope that gives you some ideas of how you can handle this.